# Clonar grupo de inputs con diferente id

Tags: javascript, function, id, clone

Tengo un grupo de inputs que quiero clonar el cual 2 de ellos tendran id diferente para poder ejecutar una function() al hacer onchange ya que en mis inputs tengo estos datos:

- Codigo -> select -> lo lleno con datos extraidos de una BD. (evento onchange) que llenara descripcion
- Descripcion -> text -> se llenara automaticamente con la dunction
- unidad de medida -> text -> tambien se llenara con datos de la BD dependiendo el codigo que se ingreso
- cantidada -> number -> contidad que el usuario de sea agregar

**Los id que quiero diferentes son codigo y descripcion para poder saber que select leere al momento de ejecutar la function y DESCRIPCION para saber donde colocar la descripcion del articulo que se selecciono en el select**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark table-responsive-lg" id="tabla">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Descripcíon</th>
                    <th scope="col">UM</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr class="fila-fija">
                    <td width="20%">
                        <select name="codigo[]" id="codigo1" required>
                            <option value="<? echo $dato['codigo']; ?>"><? echo $dato['codigo']; ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion[]" id="descrip1" required />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            campo requerido
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="8%">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="um[]" id="um1" required />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            campo requerido
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10%"><input type="number" min="10" pattern="^[0-9]+" class="form-control cantidad" name="cantidad[]" required/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            min 10
                        </div>
                     </td>
                    <td width="7%" class="eliminar"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger elimina" value=" - " disabled="disabled"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="btnAdd" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-12">  
            <label>Puedes agremar mas articulos :</label> <button type="button" id="adicional" name="adicional" class="btn btn-warning ml-2  mr-2"> Más + </button>
        </div>
        <div id="respuesta" class="col-md-6 col-12"></div>
    </div>
```

```
$('#adicional').on('click',function(){

  var suscripcion = document.getElementsByName("options");
  var num = $('.fila-fija').length;
  var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
  var numSus = 4;

  for(var i=0;i<suscripcion.length;i++)
    {
      if(suscripcion[i].checked)
      suscripcionSelect=suscripcion[i].value;
    }

  $('#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)').clone().appendTo('#tabla');

  $('.elimina').attr('disabled', false);

  if(newNum == numSus)
    $('#adicional').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});


$(document).on('click','.elimina',function(){

  var parent = $(this).parents('tr').get(0);
  var num = $('.fila-fija').length;
  var numSus = new Number(1);
  $(parent).remove();

  $('#adicional').attr('disabled', false);
    console.log(num);
  if(num-1 == numSus)
    
  $('.elimina').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas ID para acceder a los elementos, es más sencillo obtener la fila con [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) y, desde ahí, encontrar los demás elementos por nombre usando [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) con el selector apropiado.

Escuchar cambios en selects, aunque no hayan sido creados todavía, se pueden delegar fácilmente y, para entender un poco mejor, revisa los [ejemplos](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) de cómo se hacía antes y cómo se debe hacer ahora, con el método [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
// Esta puede ser una constante global, porque no se modifica posteriormente
const numSus = 4;

// Escuchar cambios en select, delegando con el método .on()
$('#tabla tbody').on('change', 'select', function() {
    // Obtener valor seleccionado
    let value = $(this).val();
    // Encontrar campo de descripción, buscando en la misma fila
    let desc = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="descripcion[]"]');
    // Asignar valor
    $(desc).val(`Valor seleccionado: ${value}`);
});

$('#adicional').on('click', function() {
    let suscripcion = document.getElementsByName("options");
    // Se necesita el número para activar el botón de esta fila
    let num = $('#tabla tbody tr.fila-fija').length;

    for(var i = 0; i < suscripcion.length; i++) {
        if(suscripcion[i].checked) {
            suscripcionSelect = suscripcion[i].value;
        }
    }
    // Clonar primera fila y agregar a tabla
    $('#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)').clone().appendTo('#tabla');
    // Activar el botón de esta fila
    $(`#tabla tbody .elimina:eq(${num})`).attr('disabled', false);
    if(num == numSus - 1) {
        // Desactivar botón cuando ya hay el máximo de filas
        $('#adicional').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});


$(document).on('click', '.elimina',function() {
    // Remoer directamente la fila
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    // Activar nuevamente el botón para agregar filas
    $('#adicional').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-dark table-responsive-lg" id="tabla">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Descripcíon</th>
                    <th scope="col">UM</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr class="fila-fija">
                    <td width="20%">
                        <select name="codigo[]" required>
                            <option>-- Selecciona --</option>
                            <option value="1">Código 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Código 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Código 3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion[]"  required />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            campo requerido
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="8%">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="um[]" required />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            campo requerido
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10%"><input type="number" min="10" pattern="^[0-9]+" class="form-control cantidad" name="cantidad[]" required/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            min 10
                        </div>
                     </td>
                    <td width="7%" class="eliminar"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger elimina" value=" - " disabled></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    <div id="btnAdd" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-12">  
            <label>Puedes agremar mas articulos :</label> <button type="button" id="adicional" name="adicional" class="btn btn-warning ml-2  mr-2"> Más + </button>
        </div>
        <div id="respuesta" class="col-md-6 col-12"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me ha servido demasiado. Tema cerrado

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por la respuesta,
Asi es como lo adapte para recibir una respuesta con Ajax para llenar el compo de Descripcion y Unudad de Medida

```
// Escuchar cambios en select, delegando con el método .on()
$('#tabla tbody').on('change', 'select', function() {
    // Obtener valor seleccionado
    let value = $(this).val();
    // Encontrar campo de descripción, buscando en la misma fila
    let desc = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="descripcion[]"]');
    // Encontrar campo de Unidad, buscando en la misma fila
    let um = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="um[]"]');
    //Consulta de codigo envio y respuesta
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '../php/procesos.php',
      data: {Bcodigo: value, accion : 'verifArticulo'},
      success:function(resAutentic){
        if(resAutentic == 'error'){
              // Recibimos respuesra de error de la consulta Ajax
              $(desc).val(`Articulo no encontrado`);
        } else {
          //El codigo se encuentra en nuestra base de datos
           $(desc).val(resAutentic.descripcion);
           $(um).val(resAutentic.unidad);
        } 
      },
      onFailure: function(){
        //Falla de coneccion
        $('#respuestaBusqueda').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Fallo en la conexión con el servidor, Intentelo mas tarde!</strong></div>');
      }
    });
});
```